# How to transfer any ERC20 token in Solidity from my smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, erc-20, contract-debugging

I am having trouble with transfering ERC20 tokens in my smart contract. Code is below. Take a look at function hodl, I want to deposit any token to this smart contract, but although I make a transaction no tokens are transfered, I am not sure why because I do call transferFrom function. Tried with transfer as well in desperation but that's probably only for token smart contract transfers.

What I am trying to develop here is a smart contract that will accept a token deposit and hold it until a time limit defined by the user when making a transaction expires.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract ERC20Interface {
function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint);

function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance);

function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public constant returns (uint remaining);

function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);

function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);

function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);

event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
}

contract hodlForYouContractV3 {

event Hodl(address indexed hodler, address token, uint  amount, uint timeLimit);

event PanicSell(address indexed hodler, address token, uint  amount, uint timediff);

event Withdrawal(address indexed hodler, address token, uint  amount);

struct Hodler {
    uint etherBalance;
    address hodler;
    mapping(address => Token) tokens;
}

struct Token {
    bytes32 symbol;
    uint tokenBalance;
    address tokenAddress;
    uint timeLimit;
}

mapping(address => Hodler) public hodlers;


function hodl(address token, byte tokenSymbol, uint256 amount, uint256 timeLimit) {

    hodlers[msg.sender] = Hodler(0, msg.sender);
    Hodler hodler = hodlers[msg.sender];
    hodler.tokens[token] = Token(tokenSymbol, amount, token, timeLimit);
    //        hodler.tokens[token].timeLimit = timeLimit;
    //        hodler.tokens[token].tokenBalance = amount;
    ERC20Interface(token).approve(msg.sender, amount);
    ERC20Interface(token).transfer(this, amount);
    ERC20Interface(token).transferFrom(msg.sender, this, amount);
    Hodl(msg.sender, token, amount, timeLimit);

}


function withdraw(address token) {
    Hodler hodler = hodlers[msg.sender];
    require(block.timestamp > hodler.tokens[token].timeLimit);

    uint amount = hodler.tokens[token].tokenBalance;
    hodler.tokens[token].tokenBalance = 0;
    ERC20Interface(token).approve(msg.sender, amount);
    ERC20Interface(token).transferFrom(this, msg.sender, amount);

    Withdrawal(msg.sender, token, amount);

}


function panicSell(address token) {
    //This function should have a fee for quicker withdrawing without waiting
    Hodler hodler = hodlers[msg.sender];

    uint amount = hodler.tokens[token].tokenBalance;
    hodler.tokens[token].tokenBalance = 0;
    ERC20Interface(token).approve(msg.sender, amount);
    ERC20Interface(token).transferFrom(this, msg.sender, amount);

    PanicSell(msg.sender, token, amount, hodler.tokens[token].timeLimit - block.timestamp);

}

}
```

Comment: hodlers[msg.sender] = Hodler(0, msg.sender);
Your structure has 3 elements, you only give it two.
Moreover, you did not implement the function for the token standard

Comment: 3 element parameter is a mapping which I handle on next line. What function for the token standard?

Comment: @Andromelus Did you try it? You're allowed to initialize a struct like this. The value that's not specified just gets its default value. Also, there's no reason to implement the ERC20 token standard functions because this contract is not a token.

Comment: But he tries to use the functions without implementing them from what I understand

Comment: I am casting a token address to a token contract, functions are implemented in the tokens smart contract, at least that's what I read somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line doesn't make sense:

```
ERC20Interface(token).approve(msg.sender, amount);
```

There are two actors in an `approve` call: the token owner and the token spender.

The token owner calls `approve(spender, amount)` so that the spender can then spend those tokens.

Here, the contract is the token owner and the user who called the function is the spender.

I think what you want is for *the user* to call `approve(contract, amount)` before calling `hodl`, and then you want to do `token.transferFrom(msg.sender, this, amount)` to transfer those tokens from the user to the contract.

Comment: So I need to make these as two separate transactions to work properly and give permission to the contract to transfer tokens?

Comment: Yes. Hopefully it's clear why this has to be the case: otherwise your contract could just steal tokens from anyone. :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will test this now, implementing two functions like you suggested. I will have to worry about security of course but first to make it work at all :)

Comment: This is not working, I tried making two functions and calling first one, when transaction finishes calling the second but still no tokens are sent.
approve line, I get approval event in the remix ide logs            
ERC20Interface(token).approve(this, amount);

Comment: The first call has to be the user calling `approve` on the token contract.

Comment: To clarify, the user should do `tokenContract.approve(hodlContractAddress, amount)` and then `hodlContract.hodl(tokenContractAddress, ...)`. Inside the `hodl` function, you just call `transferFrom`.